# Python button to change style of html div

Tags: python, html, css

I have a project in python that will hide a div when my icon is clicked and then collapse when it is clicked again. Right now I have the following html code

```
<img scr="/path/to/img"></img>
<div>
    <p>Press the icon to see more stuff</p>
</div>

<div id="showOrHide" style="display: none;">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
</div>
```

So my question is what is the best way to remove the style on the div with the id showOrHide when the user clicks on the image?

Thanks!

Comment: What does Python have to do in this project?

Comment: Why do you mention Python? There's no Python involved in what you've shown (and unless you want a round trip to the server, probably not in what you want to implement). Are you using a web app framework? Which one?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Python isn't best equipped to do what you're trying to accomplish - is there no way you can use Javascript? A simple `onclick()` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp will get the job done in JS.